# Is it possible to create a custom work Item type inside work item type in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I tried to create a new custom WIT inside some existing WIT, is it possible to do like that and one more I can't able to disable Test case WIT in new custom process.

Comment: What do you mean "inside work item"?

Answer (score -1):

WIT is separate entity in Azure DevOps and may be created without any conditions. If you want to create some hierarchy and relations you may use links between work items. 
Test Case can not be disabled. But you may prevent creation of it with rules:

[image]